# Null return on XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode through valid xpath (did try the old answer)

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, null

I've read the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543862/null-return-on-xmldocument-selectsinglenode-through-valid-xpath) and apply the answer to my code, but it still doesn't work.
I use xml to read the csproj file to read/write something into it body. 
[This](https://gist.github.com/longtth/8e440e1258386caca5e49e09dcee7066) is my csproject file if anyone care!
My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = @"D:\Project\svn_longnx\LearnSvnRevision\ConsoleApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1.csproj";
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(file);
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("default", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

    XmlElement root = xdoc.DocumentElement;

    XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("Project/PropertyGroup/ApplicationVersion",nsmgr);

    Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
}
```

This dummy code failed either:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = @"D:\Project\svn_longnx\LearnSvnRevision\ConsoleApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1.csproj";
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(file);
        XmlElement root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("Project/PropertyGroup/ApplicationVersion");
        Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Tip: Use `XDocument` and associated objects instead of the older `XmlDocument`

Comment: You added a namespace to the Manager, but don't use it in xpath.
Use `"default:Project/default:PropertyGroup/default:ApplicationVersion"`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov : it's still null.  https://imgur.com/p90RofB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to use `XDocument` and associated objects instead of the older `XmlDocument` bits. Also, you're probably falling down because of namespaces. Instead, try this code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Project\svn_longnx\Lear...\WindowsFormsApp1.csproj");
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

var applicationVersionElements = doc.Element(ns + "Project")
    .Descendants(ns + "PropertyGroup")
    .Descendants(ns + "ApplicationVersion");

foreach (var element in applicationVersionElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
}
```

This is just one way as an example of how to get that specific element to demonstrate how easy it is to use.

Note, you may need to add `using System.Xml.Linq;`